# Trying to return only ipv4 address from hostname

Tags: powershell

So my code looks like this

```
Write-Host "TECH ID's `n Ador: 1`n Len: 2 `n Colleen: 3 `n Angel: 4 `n Simon: 5 `n Brian: 6`n Jennifer : 7 `n Tina 8 `n"
$tech_name = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter Tech ID or IP"
Write-Host "Please Wait, Do not click or type anything."
& "M:\Forms\1 FS Remote\FS_remoteassistance.exe"
Sleep 3

$ping = New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate("C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe")
Sleep 2
if ($tech_name -eq "brian" -or $tech_name -eq "6" ){
    $wshell.SendKeys($($ping.Send("xxxxx").Address).IPAddressToString)
    $wshell.SendKeys("~")
}
Elseif ($tech_name -eq "angel" -or $tech_name -eq "4"){
    $wshell.SendKeys($($ping.Send("xxxxx").Address).IPAddressToString)
    $wshell.SendKeys("~")
    }
Elseif ($tech_name -eq "len" -or $tech_name -eq "2"){
    $wshell.SendKeys($($ping.Send("xxxxx").Address).IPAddressToString)
    $wshell.SendKeys("~")
    }
Elseif ($tech_name -eq "colleen" -or $tech_name -eq "3"){
    $wshell.SendKeys($($ping.Send("xxxxx").Address).IPAddressToString)
    $wshell.SendKeys("~")
    }
Elseif ($tech_name -eq "ador" -or $tech_name -eq "1"){
    $wshell.SendKeys($($ping.Send("xxxxx").Address).IPAddressToString)
    $wshell.SendKeys("~")
    }
Elseif ($tech_name -eq "simon" -or $tech_name -eq "5"){
    $wshell.SendKeys([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("")[0])
    $wshell.SendKeys("~")
    }
Elseif ($tech_name -eq "7"){
    $wshell.SendKeys($($ping.Send("xxxxx").Address).IPAddressToString)
    $wshell.SendKeys("~")
    }
Elseif ($tech_name -eq "8"){
    $wshell.SendKeys($($ping.Send("xxxxxx").Address).IPAddressToString)
    $wshell.SendKeys("~")
    }
Else{
    $wshell.SendKeys($tech_name)
    $wshell.SendKeys("~")
    }
```

So the goal of this script is to take a hostname and return the ipv4 address so that clients can run the program and connect to technicians without knowing their ip address. The problem is I need this to only send the ipv4 address, but on some computers its sending the ipv6 and on others its sending ipv4. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know why you are using two different calls to get the IPs, but this will return the IPv4 for the named system ...

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($env:COMPUTERNAME).
    Where({$_.AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetwork'}).
    IPAddressToString
```

replace the `$env:COMPUTERNAME` with your target system name and that otta give you what you need. [*grin*]

the above requires ps4+ to use the `.Where()` array method. here's one that uses the pipeline & the `Where-Object` technique. it SHOULD work on ps2, but i cannot test that.

```
([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($env:COMPUTERNAME) |
    Where-Object {$_.AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetwork'}).
    IPAddressToString
```

Comment: Im getting an error with this on windows 7 computers 
"Method invocation failed because [System.Net.IPAddress[]] doesn't contain a method named
 'Where'."

Comment: ah! you are hitting non-updated systems running ps2, apparently. [*sigh ...*] you will need to replace the `.Where()` [introduced in ps4] with `| Where-Object`. i will go back and edit that answer to include the ps2 version.